# Paste same hyperlink to all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a hyperlink on cell B1 of Sheet1. I would like to copy this exact hyperlink to cell B1 of all sheets in my workbook.

I tried copying the link, selecting all sheets and pasting, but this is not working for some reason. I also have over 50 sheets.

**Update**: Here's what I tried. It pastes the 'hyperlink' on all sheets in the workbook, but the hyperlink does not work for some reason.

```
Sub ReturnToSheet1()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
    ws.Activate

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "return to sheet1"
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 7.5
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "return to sheet1"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "Sheet1!A1", TextToDisplay:="return to sheet1"
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 10
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorHyperlink
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
End With
Selection.Font.Size = 11
Range("A3").Select

End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to copy to each sheet, one at a time. There will be a macro for it as soon as you write it. If you run into problems writing it, come back and show us your code and we'll be able to help.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, see my update above. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add _
              Anchor:=ws.Range("B1"), _
              Address:="", _
              SubAddress:="Sheet1!A1", _
              TextToDisplay:="return to sheet1"
        End If
    Next ws
```

Should be enough to do the job

Comment: I updated your code to avoid the Select/Activate.  Feel free to roll back if you don't like it